# fetch() POST request returns "Error 415 Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, hubspot-api

When trying to upload a PDF file using fetch(), I keep getting a 415 error. The PDF file is saved in the same directory as the js file, and the name is definitely correct.

```
async function uploadFile(filePath, extension, timestamp) {

    const url = "https://api.hubapi.com/files/v3/files";
    // const url = "https://api.hubapi.com/filemanager/api/v3/files/upload"; // also doesn't work.
    var filename = `${filePath}.${extension}`;

    var fileOptions = {
        access: 'PRIVATE',
        overwrite: false,
        duplicateValidationStrategy: 'NONE',
        duplicateValidationScope: 'ENTIRE_PORTAL'
    };

    var formData = {
        file: fs.createReadStream(filename),
        fileName: `${filename} (${timestamp}).${extension}`,
        options: JSON.stringify(fileOptions),
        folderPath: 'Quotations'
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, { 
            "method": "POST",
            "formData": formData,
            "headers": {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
            }
        });

        if(!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error. Response not ok: ${response.status}`);
        }
        
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    }

}

const fileId = uploadFile("Quotation", "pdf", getCurrentTimestamp());
fileId.then((data) => console.log(data));
```

I have tried changing the "Content-Type" in `headers` to several different options, and all spit back 400 and 415 errors:

`"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` - "Error: Error: HTTP Error: 400".

`"Content-Type": "application/json"` - "Error: Error: HTTP Error: 415".

`"Content-Type": "text/plain"` - "Error: Error: HTTP Error: 415".

Excluding "Content-Type" returns - "Error: Error: HTTP Error: 400".

When I use request.post() instead of fetch(), I can upload the file. But I want to use fetch().

Comment: Change the content type to multipart/form-data, and pass the form data to the request body. try this way

Comment: @Bennison J Thanks for your suggestion. However, doing that returns `Error 400 Bad Request`. Did I do this right?: 

`const response = await fetch(url, {"method": "POST", "body": formData, headers": { 'Authorization': \`Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}\`, "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } });`

Answer (score 0):

Use `form-data` to upload files:

Try this:

```
const stats = require('fs').statSync(filename);
const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;


const FormData = require('form-data');

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filename), {
    filename: filename,
    contentType: 'application/pdf',
    knownLength: fileSizeInBytes
});
formData.append('fileName', `${filename} (${timestamp}).${extension}`);
formData.append('options', JSON.stringify(fileOptions));
formData.append('folderPath', 'Quotations');


try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        "method": "POST",
        "body": formData,
        "headers": {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
            ...formData.getHeaders()
        }
    });

    //...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I'm still getting: "Error 400 Bad Request" returned as HTML.

Comment: Thank you once again, but I'm afraid I'm still getting a 400 error: `Error: Error: HTTP Error: 400`.

Comment: did you try with `axios`: `await axios.post(url, formdata, {headers...})`

Comment: Yes I did, and that didn't work either. I've found a solution that doesn't use fetch(), but instead uses request.post(). I wrap the post request in a `return new Promise(resolve, reject)`, and then `resolve(fileId)`.
Thanks for your efforts to help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same frustration. Checking out your last comment switching from `fetch` to `request.post()`.